# Oracle SQL query for Year

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select null link, CRIME_DATE label, SUM(CRIME_NO) value1
from  "C3348242"."CRIME"
group by CRIME_DATE 
order by CRIME_DATE DESC
```

I currently have this SQL query but it is not giving me the results that I desire. I want to select all the crimes that occurred in a certain year and order them by the different years for example all the crime 2013, 2014 etc. I want to get the year from the Crime_date column which is stored as DATE datatype. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a WHERE clause in your query to specify a certain year.

Comment: @FumblesWithCode I don't think he wants to query for certain years. He wants all years and then he will sort. He would not need a WHERE for this since he is getting everything from CRIME_DATE

Comment: @sealz, good point. You are right - I can see now that he wants to GROUP BY year, not SELECT for a certain year :)

Comment: I read it wrong at first as well. If the poster verifies someone can edit to make it a little clearer.

Comment: also do you want to count the crime_no and not sum it up?

Comment: yea i want all the years not one specific year

Comment: Also I should have mentioned i am using this query to produce a chart in application builder

Answer (score 1):

You can get the year using `extract`:

```
select extract(year from CRIME_DATE) year
,      null link
,      CRIME_DATE label
,      SUM(CRIME_NO) value1
from   "C3348242"."CRIME"
group
by     extract(year from CRIME_DATE)
,      CRIME_DATE 
order
by     extract(year from CRIME_DATE) desc
,      CRIME_DATE DESC
```

You could also use `to_char(crime_date, 'yyyy')`

Comment: This works is SQL commands on Oracle Apex but what i need it for is to produce a chart on Application express but it dosent seem to be working on there i get an error message saying failed to parse query, any ideas? thanks